# Scalable WordPress website and optimal load speed in several countries

Tags: wordpress, scalability

I am planning a scalable WordPress based web application but one of the challenges is to make it load quickly in Europe, USA, Canada and Australia. What is the best way to achieve this?

I can have web site installed on several servers in several countries and use load balancing? But in such case I would need to sync the databases of all those instances.

I think optimal way would be to use Amazon RDS cloud mysql database and I will not need to use several databases and sync them. But now sure how quickly the database can be accessed from different countries. Maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [AWS Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) is best solution for your case. If you are using AWS Cloudfront you need to just have one hosting server and one database server.

> I can have web site installed on several servers in several countries and use load balancing? But in such case I would need to sync the databases of all those instances.

If you try to implement above solution it will sky rocket your hosting cost and also will be more work to maintain that many servers and DB. So AWS Cloudfront is your best solution. Refer this video for setting up a secure wordpress website using AWS Cloudfront https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6X9jSH2wCM